# How to instruct screen reader to read 2 or more HTML element?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

i'm trying to make some HTML pages (JSP, actually) accessible.
For this reason i used some WAI-ARIA recommendations such tabindex="0", appropriate role, aria-label, aria-describedby attributes and so on...
In the code that follow, the screen reader is able to read the first  tag, but not the second. I tried many combinations of various suggested aria attributes, but really the screen reader (JAWS) can't read the second

"Company name:" "ACME INC."

```
<tr>
    <td><spring:message code="column.header.name" />:</td>
    <td class="readonly"><c:out value="${data.companyName}" /></td>
</tr>
```

Any hint?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How are you navigating with the screen reader?

Comment: I'm navigating using keyboard, tab, arrows keys, return key and so on... Justo to remember what i would like to achieve: I would like to concatenate the two table data in order to make the screen reader read something like:

"Company name:" "ACME INC."

Comment: it looks like your elements are in separate cells of the table.  a screen reader user is going to navigate cell by cell (ctrl+alt+arrowkey).  it might be strange to hear cells concatenated into one cell.  if they hear two cell values concatenated together when they navigate to one cell, then what should they hear when they navigate to the next cell?  there's a way to do what you want but i'm trying to understand the situation before recommending it.

Comment: I'm a bit suspicious of your table. Are there other rows and columns as well? "Company name" seems to be a header, so it should go in a `<th>`. If you only have this one pair, you shouldn't use a table at all, and it will be piece of cake to have it read together.

Comment: @Andy is correct. If this is a valid table scenario your "company name" should be in a th. Alternatively you are using the wrong layout or HTML to present your information. Tables should be used for tabular information, not to layout screens